# Unable to create a required list of a given size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nonetype

```
a=[[None]*3]
a=a*3
k=0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i][j]=k
        print(a)
        k=k+1
print(a)
```

> I want the output to be [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]. What I am getting
>   is [[6,7,8],[6,7,8],[6,7,8]]

Comment: This `a=[[None]*3]` gives you three references to the same list. When you change one you change them all.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I think the problem is the `a=a*3`. The `[None]*3` part should be fine.

Comment: Yes @glitch, You are right. Basically its cloning three variable references. if you think of a pointer, its pointing to the same reference of **a**.

Comment: Right @gilch. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake is Reference Change of a Variable which impacts every list element.
Go with the following approach.

```
n,m = 3, 3
a = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
k=0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i][j]=k
        k=k+1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy each list from `a` because when using multiple it creates a copy of each list that references to the same list so this way you are getting 3 identical lists that only the last iteration value is in it.

```
a=[[],[],[]]
a=[a[:], a[:], a[:]]
k=0
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        a[i][j]=k
        k+=1
print(a)
```

Output

```
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```